# fail to send email via django

Tags: python, django, email

settings.py

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.exmail.qq.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'admin@gushijielong.cn'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'p@ssword'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

and I execute following commands in Pycharm's Console:

```
In[2]: from django.core.mail import send_mail
In[3]: send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.','admin@gushijielong.cn',['sea3@qq.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

and nothing happened. It just stuck and if I try to put another command the console only prompts "Previous command is still running.Please wait or press Ctrl C in console to interrupt." and nothing at all.

It's not the smtp server problem, neither the authorization problem. Because I success send emails via Outlook with the same configuration.

Comment: Do you have access to the SMTP server's logs?

Comment: @FamousJameous I am not setting up a smtp server myself.  I just use the service from an email service provider. So I can't access the logs in this situation, can I ?

Comment: I'm guessing not. You could try using a different [backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/email/#email-backends) for debugging. That would at least tell you if Django was able to build the message successfully. You could also try using [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#module-smtplib) directly and see if that gives you more info. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Thanks!  I've solved this by replacing`EMAIL_USE_TLS = True` by`EMAIL_USE_SSL = True`